# Is it possible to overwrite kernel code by replacing the page tables?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

So it seems that you  cannot modify  kernel code because the PTE that points to it is marked as executable as opposed to writeable. I  was wondering if you  could overwrite kernel code using the following method? (this only applies to x86 and assumes we have root access so  we run the following steps as a kernel module)

1. Read in the contents of the CR3 register
2. Use kmalloc to allocate memory big enough to replicate all the PTE and the PDE
3. Copy all the paging data into the newly allocated memory using the value obtained from the CR3 register
4. Mark the relevant pages as executable and writeable
5. Overwrite the CR3 register with a pointer to the  memory we kmalloc'ed in step 2

At this point, assuming this all worked, wouldnt you  be able to overwrite return addresses and other parts of the kernel code? Whereas before doing this we would be stopped from the paging  mechanism protections?

Comment: You're already writing and executing kernel code just by loading the module. What do you aim to accomplish with these additional steps?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58512430/how-to-write-to-protected-pages-in-the-linux-kernel

Comment: The idea is to overwrite code that is not marked as writeable. Point  is to  hide code in the kernel to run some process transparently

Answer (score 1):

> 3 . Copy all the paging data into the newly allocated memory using the value obtained from the CR3 register
>
> 5 . Overwrite the CR3 register with a pointer to the memory we kmalloc'ed in step 2

These two steps might not work:

CR3 gives you an physical address; however, for reading the page data you require a virtual address. It is not even guaranteed that the PTD is currently mapped (and therefore accessible).

And to overwrite the CR3 register you need to know the physical address of the memory you have allocated using `kmalloc`; however, you only know the virtual address.

However, you might use `virt_to_phys` and `phys_to_virt` to translate physical to virtual addresses.

> Is it possible to overwrite kernel code ...?

I'm not sure, but the following attempt should work:

The page tables themselves should be read-write - at least the ones used by `kmalloc`.

Instead of copying the PTD and the page tables, you could allocate some memory using `kmalloc` which is 2 page sizes long (8 KiB if the "traditional" 4 KiB memory pages are used). This means that "your" memory block under all circumstances contains one complete memory page.

When you have the virtual addresses of the PTD and the page tables, you can re-map "your" memory page so it does no longer point to your "`kmalloc` memory" but to the kernel code you want to modify...

> At this point, assuming this all worked, wouldn't you be able to overwrite return addresses and other parts of the kernel code?

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.

But a kernel module **is** part of the kernel - so nothing stops a kernel module from doing something completely stupid (intentionally or because of a bug).

For this reason you have to be very careful when programming kernel modules.

And because "root" has the ability to load kernel modules, it is important that hackers or malware never get "root" access. Otherwise malware could be injected into the kernel using `insmod`.